# Questions' titles break free!

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, front-page

Here's what the front page looks like for me on <strike>the first iPad</strike> iPad (3rd generation), iOS 9.3.5, in Safari:

[image: freehand circles, yay!]

As you can see, the title in the circle is clearly out of its bounds, to an extent where the views count and said title overlap.

As far as I understand, this happens for very long titles only, and the longer the title, the crazier its positioning. For example, the first title is relatively long, and it's aligned way too much to the left, but less than the circled one.

Comment: While Safari on the first iPad is old, apparently it [should be supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/369403). Looks fine here, but don't have an old iPad laying around.

Comment: @HansPassant, no, that's Safari

Comment: You should review more ;)

Comment: 8 year old device... Hmmmmmm

Comment: The first question’s title is off, too. However, [iOS 9 is discontinued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history#Overview). BTW, are you sure you actually have [the _first_ iPad](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201471)? It’s not able to get beyond iOS 5 (at least officially), I have one of those. :-)

Comment: @Melebius, turns out, it’s actually a 3rd gen iPad. I literally thought it was the first one for _years_...

Comment: This has now been addressed on Meta.SE: [Question title overlap in new design when title is longer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315832/289905).